# How copy and rename copied image in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I've been wondering if this is possible on jmeter wherein I copy the original image and rename it via random string and paste it in the same dir.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, take a look at:

1. [OS Process Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter) which allows execution of arbitrary external commands and programs
2. [__RandomString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) function which can generate a random string of the specified length from the specified characters

Example setup:

[image]